# Interface not found error in zend framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

```
<?php
    include 'Zend/Soap/Autodiscover.php';
    include 'Zend/Soap/Server.php';
    $url = "http://localhost/webservice/server.php?wsdl";
    if(isset($_GET['wsdl'])){
        $autodiscover = new Zend_Soap_AutoDiscover();
        $autodiscover ->setClass('Serviceclass');
        $autodiscover ->handle();
    }
    else{
        $server = new Zend_Soap_Server($url);
        $server->setClass('Serviceclass');
        $server->handle();
    }
?>
```

When I execute the above code I got the following error:-
Fatal error: Interface 'Zend\Server\Server' not found in D:\wamp\www\zf2\library\Zend\Soap\Server.php on line 23

In php.ini file I have set the following path
include_path = ".;c:\php\includes;D:\wamp\www\zf2\library"

Zend framework 2 is in directory D:\wamp\www\zf2
My working directory is D:\wamp\www\webservice
My php version is :- 5.3.8

Comment: These class names look more like Zend Framework 1.

Comment: And you need to set up some autoloading.
`require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';
 Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance(); `

Comment: Can you please provide some sample code?

Comment: But the directory zend of zend framework 2 does't contain Loader folder?require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';

Comment: Seems as if your installation is somehow messed up. See also my comment about Zend Framework 1 and Zend Framework 2.

Comment: I have downloaded zend framework 2.4.9. After extracting the zip I have renamed the folder ZendFramework-2.4.9 to zf2 and change the php.ini file. I am not sure about the above code can you provide the code of zend framework 2. I have also changed the class names according to zend framework 2 but still got same error.

Comment: @Stefan Gehrig can u please provide me a sample code?

Comment: I just downloaded the same package and I do have the folder  `library/Zend/Loader`

Comment: With that you should be able to do `require_once 'Zend/Loader/AutoloaderFactory.php'; Zend\Loader\AutoloaderFactory::factory();`

Comment: @StefanGehrig what would the parameters passed to `Zend\Loader\AutoloaderFactory::factory();` look like in this case?

Comment: @YechielK Normally that should work without any argument because in that case it falls back to a standard autoloader. But this greatly depends on your setup.